# Prestashop hookActionProductUpdate Update not working in 1.7

Tags: hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm developing a module in prestashop I'm using hookActionProductUpdate hook to add/update the value there is no problem on first save but when I save second time language table text not updating I'm using separate table for language here is my code

```
public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
{
    $default_lang = (int) Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
    $id_product = Tools::getValue('id_product');
    $ilmit = array();
    $ilmat = array();
    $l_obj = LT::loadByIdProduct($id_product, $default_lang);
    $l_obj->ilmi = Tools::getValue('ilmi');
    $l_obj->ilma = Tools::getValue('ilma');
    $l_obj->ilmatt = Tools::getValue('ilmatt');
    $l_obj->id_product = $id_product;
    $languages = Language::getLanguages(false);
    foreach ($languages as $lang) {
        $l_obj->ilmit[$lang['id_lang']] = Tools::getValue('ilmit_' . $lang['id_lang']);
        $l_obj->ilmat[$lang['id_lang']] = Tools::getValue('ilmat_' . $lang['id_lang']);
    }

    if (!empty($l_obj) && isset($l_obj->id_l)) {
        $l_obj->update();
    } else {
        $l_obj->add();
    }
}
```

Note: Problem exist only in PS1.7.x

Kindly help me

Comment: Hi, Can you please show me the file from where this hook calls? Or may be you have not registered this hook for your module with system.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply hooks are working when I save the product I have two table 1)ps_lames and 2) ps_lames_lang when I save first time vale insert in both table but when I update only ps_lames value is updating.